# Solr full-import having Problems

Tags: solr, lucene, dataimporthandler, dih

I am running Sol 3.6 version with 5 cores.I do full import whenever my application starts up.
I am simply calling http://:/solr//dataimport?command=full-import

As of now i am facing 2 weird issues.

1. One of the core's data is empty(index got deleted).Dont know why.
2. In my query i had put restriction to load only 6 months old data.Sometimes i get data which is much older than 6 months.

Questions :
What does default "clean=true" mean?In my case it is true.Does that mean i will not see data once i execute following query?
http://:/solr//select/?q=*%3A*&version=2.2&start=0&rows=10&indent=on

Comment: clean=true means your index is dropped and a fresh import is done

Comment: Yes correct!When does it delete index?Befored oing full import or after finishing ?In my case i see data till it finishes indexing.Is it working correctly?

Comment: Nothing happens until a commit is done. With `clean=true` a DELETE query will be sent first and then the documents are indexed. But none of this is reflected in the search until a commit is done, which is usually only after the full import finishes. But if you have autocommit set, then DELETE will be reflected in the searcher as soon as the first autocommit happens.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem.

Executing full-import with clean=false means the DIH will erase all the documents from the index before importing. After the process is completely done, DIH will execute a commit, making the changes visible.

What happened to me is the following:

1. Execute full-import with a DB query that takes really long
2. Delete documents by query, with commitWithIn set.
3. Index is empty.

Besides that, this problem did not happen with autocommit configured as follow:

```
<autoCommit>
   <maxTime>1000</maxTime>
   <openSearcher>false</openSearcher>
 </autoCommit>
```

but did happen with

```
<autoCommit>
  <maxTime>1000</maxTime>
  <openSearcher>true</openSearcher>
</autoCommit>
```

and with autoSoftCommit

```
<autoSoftCommit>
  <maxTime>1000</maxTime>
</autoSoftCommit>
```